# SSIS Percentage sampling of 50% split isn't even

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, etl, ssis-2012

I have a stored procedure as a data source run through a RESULTS SET.

The second step is to use percentage sampling to split the data gathered 50/50. One half to go down one output, the remainder down the second output. The end result after some other tasks is two files that get uploaded to two separate destinations.

[image: Pecentage sampling example]

The source query is gettting 11 rows of data for the days activities in question but the percentage sampling is splitting it as 10 rows down the Trustpilot output and 1 row down the Feefo output.

How can it not understand the concept of 50%? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Microsoft pretty clearly states that this is not a bug on the documentation page for this transform. "In addition to the specified percentage, the Percentage Sampling transformation uses an algorithm to determine whether a row should be included in the sample output. This means that the number of rows in the sample output may not exactly reflect the specified percentage. For example, specifying 10 percent for an input data set that has 25,000 rows may not generate a sample with 2,500 rows; the sample may have a few more or a few less rows."

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/percentage-sampling-transformation?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft on the [documentation page for this task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/percentage-sampling-transformation), the specified percentage is not always the only factor in choosing which rows to send to the output.

> In addition to the specified percentage, the Percentage Sampling
>   transformation uses an algorithm to determine whether a row should be
>   included in the sample output. This means that the number of rows in
>   the sample output may not exactly reflect the specified percentage.
>   For example, specifying 10 percent for an input data set that has
>   25,000 rows may not generate a sample with 2,500 rows; the sample may
>   have a few more or a few less rows.

If you need a specific number of rows, you could use the `Row Sampling Transformation`. In this case, you'd want to get a row count of the data set and then use an expression to set the number of rows property of the `Row Sampling Transformation` task equal to half the row count.